# Using ArcGIS Create Fishnet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, vector-grid

Using ArcGIS 10 I want to create a fishnet with its bottom left coordinate = (-450000,-1401771.01064457)
I then want 71 rows above from this point and 79 columns right.
Based on 36000m by 36000m cells.

I am not sure if the one coordinate i have is the origin or the y a-axis coordinate.

How do I find the other coordinate so I can create the fishnet?

Comment: start by verifying the CRS and Unit(possibly GCS?) your coordinate is in. -45000 would normally be the easting. If that looks correct for a local CRS then you have it. then -1401771 would be your northing. Try using google to learn more about Coordinate Reference Systems.

Comment: if your bottom left coordinate is (-450000,-1401771.01064457) wouldn't you want 79 rows above and 79 rows right? if you want 79 left that would make your coordinate the bottom right.

Comment: (71 Rows x 79 Columns) is not equivalent to 36000m by 36000m cells.  Could you please resolve this issue and edit your post?

Comment: You say rows (and I assume you mean columns) left, which conflicts with saying the coordinate is bottom left. If you want the grid to the left of your coordinate, what you have is neither origin or Y axis. Origin for the tool is always bottom left corner of the grid. Assuming your coordinates are in meters, X would be -(36000*79) + -450000 and Y would be the same as your current coordinate. Your Y axis coordinate, assuming you don't want a rotation, is a point with the same X coordinate and any positive Y coordinate value greater than your origin's.

Comment: You are absolutely right (both of you). I meant 71 rows  above and 79 columns right. And yes my coordinates are in meters. I used your method @ChrisW and it the fishnet came out exactly the way I want, except it doesn't cover the study area (west USA). Can this be a projection or coordinate issue?

Comment: I'm unclear on why it doesn't cover the area you want - my comment was how to figure out grid origin if you wanted it to the left. If you want it to the right the coordinate you have *is* the origin, and for no rotation the Y axis coordinate is the same with any greater Y value. If that doesn't cover the area you want it may the coordinate system. Yours are obviously not GCS (lat/long), and if meters possibly UTM (but you shouldn't have neg values). That CRS may not cover what you want. What CRS is the dataframe/other layers? Can you provide a screenshot showing your data and grid attempt?

Answer (score 5):

you could do use the tool Grid Index Features which will create the grid/fishnet.

[image]